# Split String With Numbers in R

Tags: r, string

I have the following string:

```
employees

[1] "e1 e2 e3 e4 e5"
```

and i want to separate it in five different elements, like this:

```
"e1" "e2" "e3" "e4" "e5"
```

I tried to solve this problem using the following line:

```
strsplit(employees,"" )
```

which yields this result:

```
[1] "e" "1" " " "e" "2" " " "e" "3" " " "e" "4" " " "e" "5"
```

What can i do to solve the problem and avoid the separation of characters and numbers?

Thank you!

Comment: `strsplit(employees," " )[[1]]` ?

Comment: @RonakShah I'd remove the question mark LOL :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to split by space, which appears to be the separator in your data:

```
x <- "e1 e2 e3 e4 e5"
unlist(strsplit(x, " "))

[1] "e1" "e2" "e3" "e4" "e5"
```